# Add Cart button stopped working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, button, e-commerce, hook

I am trying to finish the Agile Web Development with Rails 4 book. I had a working  "Add to Cart button" with a Ajax . After I did more coding the Cart stopped working for a reason I do not know. 
I am guessing that the hook method I added in the application controller:

```
skip_before_action :authorize is the problem but I am not sure.
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Here is tha application.html.erb file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<html>
<title>Moussa Books Online Store</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body class="<%= controller.controller_name %>">
<div id="banner">
<%= image_tag("logo.png") %>
<%= @page_title || "Moussa Bookshelf" %>
</div>
<div id="columns">
<div id="side">
<div id="cart">
<% if @cart %>
<%= hidden_div_if(@cart.line_items.empty?, id: 'cart') do %>
<%= render @cart %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
</div>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www....">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www..../faq">Questions</a></li> 
<li><a href="http://www..../news">News</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www..../contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<% if session[:user_id] %>
<ul>
<li><%= link_to 'Orders', orders_path %></li>
<li><%= link_to 'Products', products_path %></li>
<li><%= link_to 'Users', users_path %></li>
</ul>
<%= button_to 'Logout', logout_path, method: :delete %>
<% end %>
</div>
<div id="main">
<%= yield %>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my store index page : app/views/store/index.html.erb

```
<% if notice %>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>
<h1>Your Pragmatic Catalog</h1>
<% if @counter > 5 %>
<p> You have accessed this page <%= pluralize( @counter, 'time') %> </p> 
<% end %>
<% cache ['store', Product.latest] do %>
<% @products.each do |product| %>
<% cache ['entry', product] do %>
<div class="entry">
<%= link_to image_tag(product.image_url), line_items_path(product_id: product), method: :create %>
<h3><%= product.title %></h3>
<%= sanitize(product.description) %>
<div class="price_line">
<span class="price"><%= number_to_currency(product.price) %></span>
<%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(product_id: product.id), remote: true %>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

And here is my Cart partial: ap/views/carts/_cart.html.erb

```
<h2>Your Cart</h2>
<table>
<%= render(cart.line_items) %>
<tr class="total_line">
<td colspan="2">Total</td>
<td class="total_cell"><%= number_to_currency(cart.total_price) %></td>
</tr>
</table>
<%= button_to "Checkout", new_order_path, method: :get %>
<%= button_to 'Empty cart', cart, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

And my line_items partial: app/views/line_items/_line_item.html.erb

```
<% if line_item == @current_item %>
<tr id="current_item">
<% else %>
<tr>
<% end %>
<td><%= line_item.quantity %>&times;</td>
<td><%= line_item.product.title %></td>
<td class="item_price"><%= number_to_currency(line_item.total_price) %></td>
</tr>
```

My carts controller:

```
Class CartsController < ApplicationController
skip_before_action :authorize, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]
before_action :set_cart, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :invalid_cart
# GET /carts
# GET /carts.json
def index
@carts = Cart.all
end

# GET /carts/1
# GET /carts/1.json
def show
end

  # GET /carts/new
  def new
  @cart = Cart.new
  end

   # GET /carts/1/edit
     def edit
     end

    # POST /carts
    # POST /carts.json
    def create
    @cart = Cart.new(cart_params)
    respond_to do |format|
    if @cart.save
    format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @cart }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
 end
end
end

# PATCH/PUT /carts/1
# PATCH/PUT /carts/1.json
def update
respond_to do |format|
if @cart.update(cart_params)
format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully updated.' }
format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @cart }
else
format.html { render :edit }
format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
end
end
end

# DELETE /carts/1
# DELETE /carts/1.json
def destroy
@cart.destroy if @cart.id == session[:cart_id]
session[:cart_id] = nil
respond_to do |format|
format.html { redirect_to store_url }
format.json { head :no_content }
end
end


private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_cart
  @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def cart_params
  params[:cart]
end
def invalid_cart
logger.error "Attempt to access invalid cart #{params[:id]}"
redirect_to store_url, notice: 'Invalid Cart'
end
end
```

And the line_items controller :

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController 
include CurrentCart
skip_before_action :authorize only: :create
before_action :set_cart, only: [:create]
before_action :set_line_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
# GET /line_items
# GET /line_items.json
def index
@line_items = LineItem.all
end
# GET /line_items/1
# GET /line_items/1.json
def show
end
# GET /line_items/new
def new
@line_item = LineItem.new
end
# GET /line_items/1/edit
def edit
end
# POST /line_items
# POST /line_items.json
def create
product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
@line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)
respond_to do |format|
if @line_item.save
format.html { redirect_to store_url }
format.js { @current_item = @line_item }
session[:counter] = 0
format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
else
format.html { render :new }
format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
end
end
end
# PATCH/PUT /line_items/1
# PATCH/PUT /line_items/1.json
def update
respond_to do |format|
if @line_item.update(line_item_params)
format.html { redirect_to @line_item, notice: 'Line item was successfully updated.' }
format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @line_item }
else
format.html { render :edit }
format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
end
end
end
# DELETE /line_items/1
# DELETE /line_items/1.json
def destroy
@line_item.destroy
respond_to do |format|
format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart, notice: 'Line item was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end
private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_line_item
@line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
end
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def line_item_params
  params.require(:line_item).permit(:product_id)
end
end
```

And finally my apllication controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
skip_before_action :authorize
# Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
# For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
protected
def authorize
unless User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
redirect_to login_url, notice: "Please log in"
end
end
end
```

And here is the trace:

```
Started GET "/assets/carts.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:01 -070
0
Started GET "/assets/line_items.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:01 -0700
Started GET "/assets/orders.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:01 -07
00
Started GET "/assets/products.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:01 -
0700
Started GET "/assets/scaffolds.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:01 -0700
Started GET "/assets/sessions.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:01 -0700
Started GET "/assets/store.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:01 -07 00
Started GET "/assets/users.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:01   -07 00
Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:01 -07 00
Started GET "/assets/jquery-ui/effect.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21: 56:01 -0700
Started GET "/assets/jquery-ui/effect-blind.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at   2015-03- 19 21:56:01 -0700
Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:01 -0700
Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:01 -0700
Started GET "/assets/admin.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:01 -0700
Started GET "/assets/carts.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:01 -0700
Started GET "/assets/line_items.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:01 -0700
Started GET "/assets/orders.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:01     -070 0
Started GET "/assets/products.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:01 -0 700
Started GET "/assets/sessions.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:01 -0 700
Started GET "/assets/store.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:01 -0700
Started GET "/assets/users.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:0 -0700
Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:02 -0700
Started GET "/assets/logo.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:02 -0700
Started GET "/assets/cs.jpg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:02 -0700
Started GET "/assets/rtp.jpg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:02 -0700
Started GET "/assets/ruby.jpg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:02 -0700
Started POST "/line_items?product_id=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:04 -07 00
SyntaxError (C:/Sites/depot/app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:3:     syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
skip_before_action :authorize only: :create
                                ^):
app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected   tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb
(0.0ms)
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb (59.0ms)

Started POST "/line_items?product_id=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:05 -07 00
SyntaxError (C:/Sites/depot/app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
skip_before_action :authorize only: :create
                                ^):
app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb
(2.0ms)
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb (56.0ms)

Started POST "/line_items?product_id=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:06 -07 00
SyntaxError (C:/Sites/depot/app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
skip_before_action :authorize only: :create
                                 ^):
app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb
(0.0ms)
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb (84.0ms)
Started POST "/line_items?product_id=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:14 -07 00
SyntaxError (C:/Sites/depot/app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
skip_before_action :authorize only: :create                                ^):
app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end

Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb
(2.0ms)
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb (54.0ms)
Started POST "/line_items?product_id=2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:15 -07 00
SyntaxError (C:/Sites/depot/app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
skip_before_action :authorize only: :create
                                ^):
app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb
(2.0ms)
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb (56.0ms)

Started POST "/line_items?product_id=2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:15 -07 00
SyntaxError (C:/Sites/depot/app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:3:    syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
skip_before_action :authorize only: :create
                                ^):
app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (2.0ms)
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb
(2.0ms)
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb (78.0ms)

Started POST "/line_items?product_id=2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:16 -07 00
SyntaxError (C:/Sites/depot/app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
skip_before_action :authorize only: :create
                                ^):
app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end

Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (10.0ms)
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb
(2.0ms)
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb (59.0ms)
Started POST "/line_items?product_id=3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:17 -07 00
SyntaxError (C:/Sites/depot/app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
skip_before_action :authorize only: :create
                                ^):
app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb
(0.0ms)
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb (54.0ms)
Started POST "/line_items?product_id=3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-19 21:56:17 -07 00
SyntaxError (C:/Sites/depot/app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:3:   syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
skip_before_action :authorize only: :create
                              ^):
app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb
(0.0ms)
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb (43.0ms)
```

Comment: need the stack trace, it's on the console running your rails server

Comment: ilan, I added the trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comma on line 3 of line items controller, and you cannot write :authorize:

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController 
  include CurrentCart
  skip_before_action :authorize, :only => :create
```

you can see the error if you watch your stack trace, after all the GET requests it says syntax error then finds your file and at the end of `line_items_controller.rb` there is a number, that number means the line where the syntax error is so you can find errors easier, normally errors are not of syntax but checking the stack will almost always let you see where the application is not working as intended
:

```
SyntaxError (C:/Sites/depot/app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:3:     syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
skip_before_action :authorize only: :create
```